# jquerytools & $.maskedinput conflict

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I need some help about a wierd problem.

I'm using jQueryTools and i'm very hapy with that but i think maskedinput plug in's $.mask() method conficts with jQueryTools's .mask() property. When I used both of them together console says "object doesnt have a method such as load()". If ı remove the masket input js from document everything is ok with overlays.

$.maskedInputs

```
$("#Phone1, #Phone2, #Gsm").mask("(999) 999 9999");
```

jQueryTools .mas()

```
var dialogsOverlay = $(".dialogs").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#fff',
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.8
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    close: ".closeDialog"
});
```

Do you have any exprience somethink like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the mask function in `maskedinput` to something else.  I renamed it to `maskMyI`.  You can basically just do a find and replace in `maskedinput` with your new name.  Then use the new name when calling the function on your page.

```
$("#Phone1, #Phone2, #Gsm").mask("(999) 999 9999");
```

becomes

```
$("#Phone1, #Phone2, #Gsm").maskMyI("(999) 999 9999");
```

in my case. Use your own function name.